# Developing an standalone app

Tags: spotify

I'd like to develop a spotify-app for LG TVs. These TVs only run JS web applications. Can I use the Spotify Apps API to develop a standalone application on that TV? Or does it require the spotify client itself to be installed?
As an alternative I've been considering to convert libspotify from C to JS, using emscripten. Could one of you guys perhaps tell me whether one of these ideas is gonna work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apps API is only available inside the Spotify desktop client, and Emscripten won't convert libspotify into Javascript.

You could use Spotify's Web API to write an application, but that is limited to searching and doing metadata requests - no playback or playlists.

Comment: Would you know if there is any other way to use libspotify in a webapp?

Comment: You'd need to host it somewhere and write your own web API on top.

Comment: Oh, sounds like some crazy fun... I'll see how far I come. Thanks for your answer!